# Send POST request to REST API via javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest

First, I read somewhere that we should not use `XMLHttpRequest`.

Second, I am a newbie in Javascript.

Third, I created a webpage to submit email and password.

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return check();">{% csrf_token %}
    <p><b>Login</b></p>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required></input>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id='new_password' ></input>
    <span id='message'>{{msg}}</span>
    <button type="submit" onclick="check()" name="Submit"><b>Submit</b></button>
</form>
```

My check function is

```
function check() {        
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "checking";
    const url = "https://<hostname/login";
    const data = {
        'email' : document.getElementById('email').value,
        'password' : document.getElementById('password').value
    };

    const other_params = {
        headers : { "content-type" : "application/json; charset=UTF-8" },
        body : data,
        method : "POST",
        mode : "cors"
    };

    fetch(url, other_params)
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                throw new Error("Could not reach the API: " + response.statusText);
            }
        }).then(function(data) {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = data.encoded;
        }).catch(function(error) {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = error.message;
        });
    return true;
}
```

This code is not working and just redirects me to the same page again and again.

Please help me understand what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Redirect using `window.location`.

Comment: @SumeshTG I want to load same page but with the response message of API.

Comment: I think no need to reload your page. You can set the data to DOM elements from the success handler of your ajax call itself

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is that you are not "intercepting" the submit event of your form so it will execute the default behavior which is `POST` to itself (since it doesn't have an instruction that tells it where to go).  Unless you can have a chance to stop this default behavior, the form will perform this action.

To intercept the form's submit event you have to tell the browser to watch out of this event and execute a custom function instead of using an event listener like below:

```
<script>

document.getElementById('whatever-form-id')
  .addEventListener('submit', check);

function check(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // and now anything else you want to do.
}

</script>
```

This will prevent your form from posting and it will execute your function instead.

Answer (score 1):

1) Your validation function always returns **true**
2) When you use `fetch..then`, its promises can be executed later than return statement

So your form will be refresh again and again. You should return false, and manually submit the form with JavaScript when you get an `onSuccess` response.

```
<script>
    function check(event) {
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "checking";

        const url = "https://localhost:8080/login";
        const data = {
            'email' : document.getElementById('email').value,
            'password' : document.getElementById('new_password').value
        };
        const other_params = {
            headers : { "content-type" : "application/json; charset=UTF-8" },
            body : data,
            method : "POST",
            mode : "cors"
        };

        fetch(url, other_params)
            .then(function(response) {
                if (response.ok) {
                    alert(response.json());
                } else {
                    throw new Error("Could not reach the API: " + response.statusText);
                }
            }).then(function(data) {
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = data.encoded;
            }).catch(function(error) {
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = error.message;
            });
        return false;
    }
</script>

<form method="POST" onsubmit="return check();">{% csrf_token %}
    <p><b>Login</b></p>
    <input type="email" id = "email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required></input>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id='new_password' ></input>
    <span id='message'>{{msg}}</span>
    <button type="submit" name="Submit"><b>Submit</b></button>
</form>
```

**Update:**

Page not refreshed, error message displayed:
[image]

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: @pratibha Can you share more information? What not working? What do you expect?

Comment: It is just refreshing the page, it is not calling the API.

Comment: @pratibha No, it's shouldn't. Please check your sources and try to add infromation from browser debugger

Comment: can you please share your html file?

Comment: can you please share the html file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182476/discussion-between-mrgrechkinn-and-pratibha).

Answer (score 1):

There were some errors in your code as I've checked, please use it like this

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return check();">{% csrf_token %}
    <p><b>Login</b></p>
    <input type="email" id = "email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>   
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id='new_password' >
    <span id='message'>{{msg}}</span>
    <button type="submit" onclick="check(event)" name="Submit"><b>Submit</b>  </button>
</form>
<script>
    function check(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "checking";

        const url = "https://hostname/login";
        const data = {"email" : document.getElementById('email').value,
                    'password' : document.getElementById('new_password').value
                    };
        const other_params = {
            headers : { "content-type" : "application/json; charset=UTF-8"},
            body : data,
            method : "POST",
            mode : "cors"
        };

        fetch(url, other_params)
            .then(function(response) {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                throw new Error("Could not reach the API: " + response.statusText);
            }
        }).then(function(data) {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = data.encoded;
        }).catch(function(error) {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = error.message;
        });
        return true;
    }
  </script>
```

Then test by changing your post URL to correct one whether working or not, for more testing use browser inspector tool to see your ajax request.

I've also put it on fiddle for your live testing http://jsfiddle.net/rajender07/xpvt214o/903616/

Thanks

Comment: @pratibha, I've only done fixing for running ajax request, i cannot work more on it, you need to figure it out by yourself and good for your learning, still I can show you the ajax post request in browser inspector: http://prntscr.com/la8ppc

Comment: @Rajendra I understand, just now i put actual hostname there but it is not working. API is not getting the hit

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would like to understand what is your object after getting the data from REST API.

Secondly, there are mistakes in the html code as well, you don't need to add `onclick` on the submit button when there you already have a `onsubmit` on the form element.

Solution, 
change 
`onsubmit="check(event);"`

`function check(e) { e.preventDefault() ... } // you can remove the return true`

Comment: I want to show the response message that API is sending. it is a string.

Comment: it is just showing "checking" message, not the response from API. API is returning a JSON.

Comment: @pratibha remove the return statement form `check` function

Comment: and nothing in browser debugger

Answer (score 0):

just going off the top of my head here but you've set the `Content-Type` to `application/json` in the headers but your body is not an JSON string

try making your body match the headers by doing

```
const other_params = {
  headers : { "content-type" : "application/json; charset=UTF-8"},
  body : JSON.stringify(data),
  method : "POST",
  mode : "cors"
};
```

**EDIT**

So after re-reading your question, I think what is happening is you've set your `button` to type of `submit` and what is happening is when you click on the button, your form is getting posted through the good old form post and your page gets refreshed from the postback.

If you want to handle form posts yourself using fetch, change your button type to `button` and the form should no longer actually post then everything else will be handled by your click event handler.

ps. while you're at it, you can remove the `method` and `onsubmit` attribute from your form tag as well

So your form should look something like this

```
<form>
    <p><b>Login</b></p>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required></input>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id='new_password' ></input>
    <span id='message'>{{msg}}</span>
    <button type="button" onclick="check()" name="Submit"><b>Submit</b></button>
</form>
```

Comment: what isn't working exactly? the page still refeshing from postback? or the returned message is not showing where you want it to?

Comment: It is stuck at "checking" message

Comment: and nothing in browser debugger